# WinError 87 when running xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I have been working with xlwings to run python from an excel workbook - the xlwings module had been worked fine, but now I am getting this error. Has anyone come across this before? This really has put me at a standstill. Thanks in advance.

---

### Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "c:\users\user\documents\python\tptdevenv\tpt\TPT.py", line 15, in main

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 613, in caller

```
return cls(impl=app.books[name].impl)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 378, in books

```
return Books(impl=self.impl.books)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 411, in books

```
return Books(xl=self.xl.Workbooks)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 327, in xl

```
self._xl = get_xl_app_from_hwnd(self._hwnd)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 236, in get_xl_app_from_hwnd

```
ptr = accessible_object_from_window(child_hwnd)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 209, in accessible_object_from_window

```
res = oledll.oleacc.AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 451, in **getattr**

```
dll = self._dlltype(name)
```

File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 381, in **init**

```
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

### Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.

### OK